# XSLT: Select following-sibling until reaching a specified tag

Tags: xml, xslt

I am attempting to write XSLT that will run a for-each on the selected following-siblings but stop when another tag (h1) is reached.

Here's the Source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<html>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <p>Test: p 1</p>
    <p>Test: p 2</p>
    <h1>Test 2</h1>
    <p>Test2: p 1</p>
    <p>Test2: p 2</p>
    <p>Test2: p 3</p>
</html>
```

Here's the XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <content>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </content>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="h1">
        <section>
            <sectionHeading>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </sectionHeading>
            <sectionContent>
                <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::p">
                    <paragraph>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </paragraph>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </sectionContent>
        </section>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here's the current result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<content>
    <section>
        <sectionHeading>Test</sectionHeading>
        <sectionContent>
            <paragraph>Test: p 1</paragraph>
            <paragraph>Test: p 2</paragraph>
            <paragraph>Test: p 3</paragraph>
            <paragraph>Test2: p 1</paragraph>
            <paragraph>Test2: p 2</paragraph>
        </sectionContent>
    </section>
    <section>
        <sectionHeading>Test 2</sectionHeading>
        <sectionContent>
            <paragraph>Test2: p 1</paragraph>
            <paragraph>Test2: p 2</paragraph>
        </sectionContent>
    </section>
</content>
```

Here's the expected result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<content>
<section>
    <sectionHeading>Test</sectionHeading>
    <sectionContent>
        <paragraph>Test: p 1</paragraph>
        <paragraph>Test: p 2</paragraph>
        <paragraph>Test: p 3</paragraph>
    </sectionContent>
</section>
<section>
    <sectionHeading>Test 2</sectionHeading>
    <sectionContent>
        <paragraph>Test2: p 1</paragraph>
        <paragraph>Test2: p 2</paragraph>
    </sectionContent>
</section>
</content>
```

Comment: @ Tim,though we can get a solution for xslt i would rather suggest you to change the xml format to
<Test>    <h1>Test</h1>
    <p>Test: p 1</p>
    <p>Test: p 2</p>
</Test>
<Test> 
    <h1>Test 2</h1>
    <p>Test2: p 1</p>
    <p>Test2: p 2</p>
    <p>Test2: p 3</p>
</Test> 
Which makes more sense and is readable,also easy to query in xslt.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try this: (Instead of asking for all the p's we ask for all the p's whose most recently preceding h1 is current.)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <content>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </content>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="h1">
        <xsl:variable name="header-id" select="generate-id(.)"/>
        <section>
            <sectionHeading>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </sectionHeading>
            <sectionContent>
                <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::p[generate-id(preceding-sibling::h1[1]) = $header-id]">
                    <paragraph>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </paragraph>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </sectionContent>
        </section>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Just tested this out and it's working perfectly. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 11):

## The accepted answer has a bad side effect and it is kinda wrong.

Further in this post, i will explain the real compare of the following essential statement and why it **can** and **will** fail.

---

*recap/analyse situation while being in template `<xsl:template match="h1">`:*

- Current context node is any `h1` from the matching `<xsl:template>`.
- variable named `header` contains a duplicate of my current context node.

The essential statement which is bad/wrong:

> following-sibling::p[preceding-sibling::h1[1] = $header]

- select all following siblings `p` of my context node | `following-sibling::p`
- filter these `p` where the first (closest) preceding-sibling named `h1` **"is"** the same as the variable `$header` | `...[preceding-sibling::h1[1] = $header]`.

**!! In XSLT 1.0 the compare of a node with a node will be done by its value !!**

---

See it in an example. Lets pretend the input xml is like this [`<h1>` contain twice the same value `Test`]:

```
<html>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <p>Test: p 1</p>
    <p>Test: p 2</p>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <p>Test2: p 1</p>
    <p>Test2: p 2</p>
    <p>Test2: p 3</p>
</html>
```

A **!WRONG!** result will be created:

```
<content>
  <section>
     <sectionHeading>Test</sectionHeading>
     <sectionContent>
        <paragraph>Test: p 1</paragraph>
        <paragraph>Test: p 2</paragraph>
        <paragraph>Test2: p 1</paragraph> <-- should be only in 2. section 
        <paragraph>Test2: p 2</paragraph> <-- should be only in 2. section 
        <paragraph>Test2: p 3</paragraph> <-- should be only in 2. section 
     </sectionContent>
  </section>
  <section>
     <sectionHeading>Test</sectionHeading>
     <sectionContent>
        <paragraph>Test2: p 1</paragraph>
        <paragraph>Test2: p 2</paragraph>
        <paragraph>Test2: p 3</paragraph>
     </sectionContent>
  </section>
</content>
```

---

## Correct compare

```
...
<xsl:template match="h1">
    <xsl:variable name="header" select="generate-id(.)"/>
    <section>
        <sectionHeading>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </sectionHeading>
        <sectionContent>
            <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::p[generate-id(preceding-sibling::h1[1]) = $header]">
                <paragraph>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </paragraph>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </sectionContent>
    </section>
</xsl:template>
...
```

Use the function [generate-id()](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#function-generate-id) to get the unique (at least in the current document) ID of a node and compare now node vs node! Even if you use this technique with `<xsl:key>`, you have to use `generate-id()`.

Comment: Why not just edit the accepted solution and add a comment?

Comment: I downvoted this because you could very well have edited the correct response or left a comment.