# Transform an HTML DL into 2-column XSL-FO table of terms and definitions

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xsl-fo, list-definition

How can I use XSLT to turn an HTML definition list (DL) into a two-column XSL-FO table with the terms in the first column and the definitions in the second, with multiple definitions possible?

(Apologies if this is already answered somewhere. I searched but did not find.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has the crux of finding the following-siblings that still have the current DT as their term:
[XSLT: Select following-sibling until reaching a specified tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165566/xslt-select-following-sibling-until-reaching-a-specified-tag)

Then it's just a matter of defining the whole table as the top-level DL template:

```
<xsl:template match="dl">
    <fo:table>
        <fo:table-body>
            <xsl:for-each select="dt">
                <xsl:variable name="current-term" select="."/>
                <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell font-weight="bold" width="5.5cm">
                        <fo:block>
                            <xsl:apply-templates />
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::dd[preceding-sibling::dt[1] = $current-term]" />
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </fo:table-body>
    </fo:table>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="dd">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```