# XSLT Mappings for Sibling nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, biztalk, hl7

My Input XML is like below:

```
<ORU>
  <OBR>
    <OBR_SetId>1</OBR_SetId>
  </OBR>
  <OBX></OBX>
  <OBX></OBX>
  <OBX></OBX>
  <SPM></SPM>
  <ORC></ORC>
  <OBR>
    <OBR_SetId>2</OBR_SetId>
  </OBR>
  <OBX></OBX>
  <OBX></OBX>
  <OBX></OBX>
  <OBR>
    <OBR_SetId>3</OBR_SetId>
  </OBR>
  <OBX></OBX>
  <OBX></OBX>
  <OBX></OBX>
</ORU>
```

Means, `<OBR>` is a parent & each has 3 `<OBX>` child records. I have to loop through `<OBR>` & corresponding `<OBX>` to read the values. I am using the code below. But only first `<OBR>` has child nodes that too all the `<OBX>` not 3. How to do?

```
<xsl:variable name="OBR" select="//*[local-name()='OBR_ObservationRequest' and namespace-uri()='']" />
  <xsl:for-each select="$OBR">
    <ns0:entity>
      <xsl:variable name="OBR_SetId" select="position()" />

    ................
<xsl:variable name="obx" select="//OBX_ObservationResult[preceding-sibling::OBR_ObservationRequest[1][position() = $OBR_SetId]]" />
      <xsl:if test="count($obx) &gt; 0">
<xsl:for-each select="$obx">
        .......................
```

Comment: **1.** "*<OBR> is a parent & each has 3 <OBX> child records.*" No, that's not true: the `OBX` elements are **not** children of `OBR`. **2.** What is the expected result of your example?

Comment: <OBX> is not child element but it has to come as child element in the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//OBR"/>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="//OBR">
    <xsl:variable name="header" select="."/>
    <OBR>
      <xsl:attribute name="OBR_SetId">
        <xsl:value-of select="./OBR_SetId"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <children>
        <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::OBX[preceding-sibling::OBR[1] = $header]">
          <OBX>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </OBX>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </children>
    </OBR>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When using the following input:

```
<ORU>
  <OBR>
    <OBR_SetId>1</OBR_SetId>
  </OBR>
  <OBX>1</OBX>
  <OBX>2</OBX>
  <OBX>3</OBX>
  <SPM/>
  <ORC/>
  <OBR>
    <OBR_SetId>2</OBR_SetId>
  </OBR>
  <OBX>4</OBX>
  <OBX>5</OBX>
  <OBX>6</OBX>
  <OBR>
    <OBR_SetId>3</OBR_SetId>
  </OBR>
  <OBX>7</OBX>
  <OBX>8</OBX>
  <OBX>9</OBX>
</ORU>
```

I get the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <OBR OBR_SetId="1">
    <children>
      <OBX>1</OBX>
      <OBX>2</OBX>
      <OBX>3</OBX>
    </children>
  </OBR>
  <OBR OBR_SetId="2">
    <children>
      <OBX>4</OBX>
      <OBX>5</OBX>
      <OBX>6</OBX>
    </children>
  </OBR>
  <OBR OBR_SetId="3">
    <children>
      <OBX>7</OBX>
      <OBX>8</OBX>
      <OBX>9</OBX>
    </children>
  </OBR>
</root>
```

FYI: this is based on a solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165566/xslt-select-following-sibling-until-reaching-a-specified-tag)