# How to apply XSL templates to start and finish XML element from different parts of the document

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to work out how to create a HTML document where sometimes a set of elements from the XML source are 'wrapped' in a bootstrap panel.

The XML describes a vertical form layout. So you have a set of rows which contain a single field. Where there is a PANELSTART field, I want to start a Panel on screen, continue to write out content and then when I hit a PANELEND field, I want to close the panel off with the matching `</div>`.  However XSL doesn't allow this as all elements need a matching end element.
I've tried

```
<xsl:text>
```

but that didn't seem to work either. I have an example for illustration.

Source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rows>
    <row><field type="B><plainValue>B0</plainValue></field></row>
    <row><field type="PANELSTART"></field></row>
    <row><field type="B"><plainValue>B1</plainValue></field></row>
    <row><field type="PANELEND"/></row>
    <row><field type="C"><plainValue>C0</plainValue></field></row>
    <row><field type="D"><plainValue>D0</plainValue></field></row>
    <row><field type="B"><plainValue>B2</plainValue></field></row>
</rows>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" />
 <xsl:template match="field[@type='PANELSTART']">
    <div class='panel'>panel header</div>
        <div class='panel-body'>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="field[@type='B']">
     <p>content goes here</p>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="field[@type='PANELEND']">
     </div>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected Result:

```
    <p>B0</p>
    <div class="panel">panel header</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
       <p>B1</p>
    </div>
    <p>C0</p>
    <p>D0</p>
    <p>B2</p>
```

I'd appreciate your thoughts on how to do this.  Unfortunately, I'm not going to be able to change the structure of the XML.

Comment: Interesting problem. Can there be multiple successive `PANELSTART/PANELEND` sections in one `rows` field?

Comment: Are you using XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0?

Comment: There's just one PANELSTART per row and one PANELEND per row.  In some ways the field element is not needed.  Originally I was going to have many fields per row, but for now it is only one field per row. Also, the Panels are not nested.  You always have a matching PANELEND for a PANELSTART.

Comment: @TimC, it's XSLT 1.0, but I could switch to 2.0 if needed.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the expected HTML in this case? Thank you!

Comment: I've implemented my solution using the accepted answer and uploaded it here http://xsltransform.net/bFDb2D8/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XSLT 1.0 you can use "sibling recursion":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="5.0"/>

    <xsl:template match="rows">
        <div>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="row[1]"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="row[field[@type = 'PANELSTART']]">
        <div class="panel">panel header</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]"/>
        </div>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::row[field[@type = 'PANELEND']][1]/following-sibling::*[1]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="row">
        <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </p>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1][not(self::row[field[@type = 'PANELEND']])]"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Online at http://xsltransform.net/bdxtqY/2.

Comment: Thanks Martin, see my edit of the XML.  Your solution worked for my initial example, but my initial example was lacking.  I've been playing with your code at http://xsltransform.net/6qVRKx3 to see if I can make it work.  I appreciate the link to xsltransform.net - I hadn't come across it before - very handy.  I'll carry on looking at the example and other answers tomorrow.

Comment: This looks similar.  I might be able to use something from this with your example. [Following sibling until reaching a specific tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165566/xslt-select-following-sibling-until-reaching-a-specified-tag)

Comment: @JohnTempler, I have edited the code to cover more complex cases, still using sibling recursion.

Comment: Thanks Martin, that worked nicely.  Much appreciated.

Comment: I've implemented my final solution using your answer uploaded here http://xsltransform.net/bFDb2D8/2

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to use XSLT 2.0, you could potentially make us of `xsl:for-each-group` together with its `group-starting-with` attribute

```
 <xsl:for-each-group select="row/field" group-starting-with="field[@type='PANELSTART']">
```

So, each field with a type attribute of "PANELSTART" forms the start of each group.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="rows">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="row/field" group-starting-with="field[@type='PANELSTART']">
        <div class='panel'>panel header</div>
            <div class='panel-body'>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />                
            </div>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="field[@type='B']">
        <p>content goes here</p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="field[@type='PANELEND']" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You could probably drop the template matching "PANELEND" though.

Read up on xsl:for-each-group at http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/11/05/tr.html

Comment: This looks interesting.  I will have a read tomorrow.  I've updated my XML example as it didn't reflect my real situation enough.

Answer (score 0):

This XSLT ignores all `PANELSTART` and `PANELEND` rows (in fact everything not `B` – but if necessary, it can be reorganized to ignore *only* `PANELSTART` and `PANELEND`). It loops not over `fields`, but over `rows` instead. That means that the entire set of `field/type B` get treated as a single entity, and so you can insert a `div` around it.

It will work correctly with multiple occurrences of `rows` (each one will get a `div` of its own), and will ignore the entire sets of `fields` when there is no "type B" in it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" />

 <xsl:template match="rows">
    <xsl:if test="row/field/@type='B'">
    <div class='panel'>panel header</div>
    <div class='panel-body'>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="row/field[@type='B']" mode="process" />
    </div>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="field[@type='B']" mode="process">
    [<xsl:value-of select="." />]
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```