# XSLT wrap specified element under condition in new parent tag

Tags: python, xml, xslt, tags, elementtree

I have an XML structured like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<pages>
<page id="1" bbox="0.000,0.000,462.047,680.315" rotate="0">
<textbox id="0" bbox="191.745,592.218,249.042,603.578">
<textline bbox="191.745,592.218,249.042,603.578">
<text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="191.745,592.218,199.339,603.578" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="11.360">A</text>
<text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="199.227,592.218,205.657,603.578" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="11.360">P</text>
<text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="205.545,592.218,211.975,603.578" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="11.360">P</text>
<text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="211.023,592.218,218.617,603.578" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="11.360">A</text>
<text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="218.515,592.218,226.109,603.578" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="11.360">R</text>
<text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="226.008,592.218,233.602,603.578" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="11.360">A</text>
<text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="232.812,592.218,240.932,603.578" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="11.360">T</text>
<text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="240.922,592.218,249.042,603.578" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="11.360">O</text>
</textline>
</textbox>
<textbox id="1" bbox="44.614,554.008,58.101,564.246">
<textline bbox="44.614,554.008,58.101,564.246">
<text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="44.614,554.008,49.369,564.246" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="10.238">2</text>
<text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="49.268,554.008,54.022,564.246" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="10.238">4</text>
<text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="53.922,554.008,58.101,564.246" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="10.238">a</text>
</textline>
</textbox>
<textbox id="2" bbox="43.563,475.008,58.117,485.246">
<textline bbox="43.563,475.008,58.117,485.246">
<text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="43.563,475.008,48.317,485.246" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="10.238">2</text>
<text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="48.226,475.008,52.980,485.246" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="10.238">4</text>
<text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="52.889,475.008,58.117,485.246" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="10.238">b</text>
</textline>
</textbox>
</page>
</pages>
```

It is actually way longer. I want to insert a `<newline>` parent tag every time there is a certain distance between the first number of the bbox attribute and the first number and the next bbox attribute. I want that the tag is closed only when there is the need to open another one. Everything works, but I don't know how wrap those text elements as I'm new to XSLT.

This is the code so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" />

  <xsl:template match="textbox">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="textline" />  
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="textline">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="text" />  
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text[@bbox and text()]">
    <!-- each @bbox has this format: "x1,y1,x2,y2" (top-left/bottom-right coordinates) -->
    <xsl:variable name="x1this" select="number(substring-before(@bbox, ','))" />
    <xsl:variable name="x2prev" select="number(substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(preceding-sibling::text[@bbox][1]/@bbox, ','), ','), ','))" />
    <xsl:variable name="distance" select="$x1this - $x2prev" />
    <xsl:variable name="nextCharacter" select="following-sibling::text[normalize-space()][1]" />
    <xsl:variable name="isEOL" select="not($nextCharacter)" />
    <xsl:variable name="isHyphen" select=". = '-'" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$distance &gt; 10">
          <newline></newline>          
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$distance &gt; 2">
            <whitespace></whitespace><!-- regular space for small gap -->
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$isHyphen and $isEOL"></xsl:when><!-- suppress hyphens at the end of the line -->
        <xsl:when test="not($isHyphen) and $isEOL"><xsl:copy-of select="concat(., '&#xA;')" /></xsl:when><!-- add newline at the end of non-hyphenated lines -->
        <xsl:otherwise><xsl:copy-of select="." /></xsl:otherwise><!-- output character as-is -->
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text">
    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::text"><!-- suppress end-of-line spaces, this re-connects hyphenated words -->
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EDIT: expected output below:

```
    <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="191.745,592.218,199.339,603.578" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="11.360">A</text><text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="199.227,592.218,205.657,603.578" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="11.360">P</text><text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="205.545,592.218,211.975,603.578" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="11.360">P</text><text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="211.023,592.218,218.617,603.578" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="11.360">A</text><text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="218.515,592.218,226.109,603.578" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="11.360">R</text><text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="226.008,592.218,233.602,603.578" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="11.360">A</text><text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="232.812,592.218,240.932,603.578" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="11.360">T</text>O


    <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="44.614,554.008,49.369,564.246" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="10.238">2</text><text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="49.268,554.008,54.022,564.246" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="10.238">4</text>a


    <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="43.563,475.008,48.317,485.246" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="10.238">2</text><text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="48.226,475.008,52.980,485.246" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="10.238">4</text>b


    <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="44.614,421.608,49.369,431.846" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="10.238">2</text><text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="49.268,421.608,54.022,431.846" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="10.238">4</text>c


    <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="43.563,339.508,48.317,349.746" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="10.238">2</text><text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="48.226,339.508,52.980,349.746" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="10.238">4</text>d


    <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="44.949,237.108,49.703,247.347" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="10.238">2</text><text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="49.274,237.108,54.028,247.347" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="10.238">5</text>a

    **<newline>**
    <text font="PYNIYO+ImprintMTnum-Italic" bbox="68.031,553.639,76.375,566.366" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.727">T</text>
<text font="PYNIYO+ImprintMTnum-Italic" bbox="76.231,553.639,79.479,566.366" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.727">i</text>
<text font="PYNIYO+ImprintMTnum-Italic" bbox="79.334,553.639,83.161,566.366" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.727">t</text>
<text font="PYNIYO+ImprintMTnum-Italic" bbox="83.017,553.639,88.112,566.366" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.727">o</text>
<text font="PYNIYO+ImprintMTnum-Italic" bbox="87.968,553.639,91.216,566.366" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.727">l</text>
<text font="PYNIYO+ImprintMTnum-Italic" bbox="91.071,553.639,96.167,566.366" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.727">o</text>
 <whitespace/><text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="99.311,553.628,104.406,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">I</text>
<text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="104.261,553.628,107.510,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">l</text>
<text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="107.365,553.628,110.269,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482"> </text>
 <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="110.658,553.628,119.002,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">C</text>
<text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="118.857,553.628,123.953,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">a</text>
<text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="123.808,553.628,130.183,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">u</text>
<text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="130.038,553.628,134.555,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">s</text>
<text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="134.410,553.628,137.659,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">i</text>
<text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="137.514,553.628,143.889,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">d</text>
<text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="143.744,553.628,146.993,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">i</text>
<text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="146.848,553.628,151.943,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">c</text>
<text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="151.799,553.628,157.595,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">o</text>
<text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="157.450,553.628,161.277,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">]</text>
<text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="161.132,553.628,164.036,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482"> </text>
 <text font="PYNIYO+ImprintMTnum-Italic" bbox="164.417,553.639,168.244,566.366" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.727">s</text>
<text font="PYNIYO+ImprintMTnum-Italic" bbox="168.099,553.639,173.895,566.366" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.727">p</text>
<text font="PYNIYO+ImprintMTnum-Italic" bbox="173.751,553.639,177.578,566.366" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.727">s</text>
<text font="PYNIYO+ImprintMTnum-Italic" bbox="176.966,553.639,180.215,566.366" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.727">.</text>
<text font="PYNIYO+ImprintMTnum-Italic" bbox="180.070,553.639,182.974,566.366" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.727"> </text>
 <text font="PYNIYO+ImprintMTnum-Italic" bbox="183.363,553.639,189.159,566.366" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.727">a</text>
 <whitespace/><text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="192.314,553.628,201.937,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">D</text><text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="201.793,553.628,207.589,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">o</text><text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="207.444,553.628,213.819,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">n</text><text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="213.674,553.628,216.578,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482"> </text> <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="216.967,553.628,225.311,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">R</text><text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="225.166,553.628,230.962,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">o</text><text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="230.818,553.628,237.192,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">d</text><text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="237.048,553.628,241.565,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">r</text><text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="241.420,553.628,244.668,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">i</text><text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="244.524,553.628,250.320,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">g</text><text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="250.064,553.628,255.860,566.110" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">o</text> <text>
    </text>
    **</newline>**
    **<newline>**
    <text font="QKWQNQ+ImprintMTnum-Bold" bbox="272.661,554.072,277.415,564.757" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="10.685">1</text>
    ... continues
**</newline>**
```

Comment: I don't see any python code. What issues were you having?

Comment: Yes, because I read the XSLT through Python. I can't manage to wrap text tags in a newline parent tag every time the distance I specify is > 10 (<xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$distance &gt; 10">
          <newline></newline>      ). I have a Python version of the problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61245945/how-to-wrap-elements-in-a-specified-parent-tag-xml-python

Comment: To my understanding, wapping something into a new element would be e.g. `<newline><xsl:copy-of select="."/></newline>` to wrap the currently processed `text` into a `newline` element. It would really help if you showed us the result XML you want to create.

Comment: I changed the question so that you could see the expected output! because it works as you put it, the problem is it only wraps one text tag while I want multiple ones

Comment: The usual way to wrap several adjacent elements in XSLT 1 based on a condition is to use sibling recursion, sometimes it is also possible to use a key on preceding or following sibling node id. To allow others to better understand your core problem it would help if you strip the samples of all irrelevant data. And you will need to explain in more detail when you want to wrap the elements and when not.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] with a clear definition of the problem and the logic that needs to applied in order to solve it. *"insert a <newline> parent tag every time there is a certain distance between the first number of the bbox attribute and the first number and the next bbox attribute"* is too vague, even confusing.

Answer (score 0):

As @MartinHonnen says in his comment, the classic solution to this problem is sibling recursion.

The essence of this technique is:

- from the parent element `textline` you apply-templates to the first child `text` element: `<xsl:apply-templates select="text[1]"/>`
- from the child element `text` you apply-templates to the following-sibling element: `<xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::text[1]"/>`

There's a worked example of the technique at

[How to apply XSL templates to start and finish XML element from different parts of the document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31648822/how-to-apply-xsl-templates-to-start-and-finish-xml-element-from-different-parts/31649414#31649414)

See if you can adapt it.

Comment: There is no classic solution to an ill-defined problem.