# selecting every node and siblings until next occurrence

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

With this xml structure :

```
<doc>
    <members>
    <member name="T:XXX">
    </member>
    <member name="F:YYY">
    </member>
    <member name="P:ZZZ">
    </member>
    <member name="T:XXX">
    </member>
</doc>
```

I try to get all nodes following node with name attribute starting with '**T:**' until the next node with name attribute starting with '**T:**'.

Based on this stackoverflow topic ([#40767321](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40767321/selecting-every-node-and-siblings-until-next-occurrence-of-that-node-combinati)), I found an almost perfect answer.

With the **xsl:key** below, it takes the first **T:** node and all of the followers but it also includes the next **T:** node in the select.
How can I exlude it ?

```
<xsl:key name="subMembers" match="member" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::*[contains(@name, 'T:')][1])" />
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the linked topic, which deals with `ol` elements followed by `div` elements, the key is only matching the `div` elements. However, in your question, the **T:** nodes represent the `ol` elements and the key is matching these elements.

You need to replace the key to ignore the **T:** nodes

```
<xsl:key name="subMembers" match="member[not(starts-with(@name, 'T:'))]" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::*[starts-with(@name, 'T:')][1])" />
```

So, assuming you start off by selecting the **T:** nodes, you would select those nodes, and the associated nodes, like so:

```
 <xsl:copy-of select="self::*|key('subMembers', generate-id())" />
```

(Or you could use `xsl:for-each` or `xsl:apply-templates` should you also wish to transform the group elements).

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="subMembers" match="member[not(starts-with(@name, 'T:'))]" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::*[starts-with(@name, 'T:')][1])" />

<xsl:template match="members">
    <members>
        <xsl:for-each select="member[starts-with(@name, 'T:')]">
            <group>
                <xsl:copy-of select="self::*|key('subMembers', generate-id())" />
            </group>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </members>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Ok I think I got it, I'll try and come back to you! Thanks!

Comment: I tried and this is perfect ! I used a `xsl:foreach` and `call-template` instead of `xsl:copy-of`. Thanks again.