# PHP DOMDocument: grouping non-nested results

Tags: php, html, parsing, xpath, domdocument

I'm having trouble with DOMDocument/XPath. The HTML (I have no control of it) looks like this:

```
.. random html ..

<div class="separator"></div>
<div class="date">01-01-1900</div>

<div class="item"><div>1 HTML garbage</div></div>
<div class="item"><div>2 HTML garbage</div></div>


<div class="separator"></div>
<div class="date">12-12-2012</div>

<div class="item"><div>3 HTML garbage</div></div>
<div class="item"><div>4 HTML garbage</div></div>
<div class="item"><div>5 HTML garbage</div></div>
<div class="item"><div>6 HTML garbage</div></div>

.. more random html ...
```

How I need my data:

```
$result = array(
    '01-01-1900' => array(
        array('name' => '1 HTML garbage'),
        array('name' => '2 HTML garbage')
    ),
    '12-12-2012' => array(
        array('name' => '3 HTML garbage'),
        array('name' => '4 HTML garbage'),
        array('name' => '5 HTML garbage'),
        array('name' => '6 HTML garbage')
    )
);
```

Since the depth can change, I can't use a fixed path from my browser console.
How I can group by date? Right now I can get a list of the items by using:

```
$xpath->query('//*[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " item ")]');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using php you can first get all dates and iterate over those dates to get the items according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161766/xpath-select-all-following-siblings-until-another-sibling) (*untested*)

```
//../node[contains(@class,'item') and preceding-sibling::node[contains(text(),'12-12-2012')]]
```

with `12-12-2012` as the searched value.

Comment: The "date" field on my example is following a standard but real data isn't, so I can't really loop that. I could query the entire HTML for all the datas and them loop that (like it was a random string) but this seems extremely inefficient. Is this really the only way of doing it on xpath?

Comment: Thanks man, I made it work with your example. If anybody else is facing the same problem: this is way too hack-ish and I wouldn't recommend unless you have to deliver something for yesterday.