# XPath: how to select following siblings until a certain sibling

Tags: html, xpath

For the example HTML below, an XPath query that returns the siblings of the "a" elements with class='A' that have class='B' can be written as: `//a[@class='A']/following-sibling::a[@class='B']`. This query outputs 4 `<a class="B"/>` elements.

However, I would only like the `<a class="B"/>` elements that follow the current `<a class="A"/>` element, and no others that follow other `<a class="B"/>` elements/nodes. In other words, I only want the following `<a class="B"/>` sibling elements until the next `<a class="B"/>` element shows up.

Example HTML:

```
<a class='A' />
<a class='B' />
<a class='A' />
<a class='B' />
<a class='B' />
<a class='B' />
```

Any ideas on how to limit my current XPath query to just those siblings would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Wouldn't `//a[@class='A']/following-sibling::a[@class='B'][1]` do it for you?

Comment: You need to apply the Kayessian method for that. See an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10859928/3190413

Comment: possible duplicate of [XPath : select all following siblings until another sibling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161766/xpath-select-all-following-siblings-until-another-sibling)

Answer (score 16):

To select all `a` elements having a `class` attribute of `B` between some specific `a` with a `class` equal to `A` and the next such occurrence:

```
/*/a[@class='A'][$n]/following-sibling::a[
    @class='B' and count(preceding-sibling::a[@class='A'])=$n]
```

This selects everything between the *nth* `a[@class='A']` and the next such element. For a specific example, consider the following input:

```
<r>
  <a class="A"/>  
  <a class="B"/>  
  <a class="A"/>  
  <a class="B"/>  
  <a class="B"/>  
  <a class="A"/>  
  <a class="B"/>  
  <a class="B"/>  
  <a class="B"/>
</r>
```

To get the two elements between the second `<a class="A"/>` and the third `<a class="A"/>`:

```
/*/a[@class='A'][2]/following-sibling::a[
    @class='B' and count(preceding-sibling::a[@class='A'])=2]
```

In English, this says:

> Give me all of the `a` elements having a `class` attribute whose value is equal to `B` that come after the second `a` having a class attribute equal to `A` and that have only two preceding siblings having a `class` attribute equal to `A`

Similarly, and more generally, we can apply the Kayessian method for finding the intersection of two node sets. In the example given, we want the intersection of all the `@class='B'` elements in 1) the set of siblings after the second `<a class="A"/>` and 2) the set of siblings before the third `<a class="A"/>`. The intersection of these two sets is precisely the nodes that come between those two divider elements and can be expressed like this:

```
/*/a[@class='A'][2]/following-sibling::a[@class='B'][
    count(.|/*/a[@class='A'][3]/preceding-sibling::a[@class='B'])=
    count(/*/a[@class='A'][3]/preceding-sibling::a[@class='B'])]
```

Comment: I completely follow the logic of your second xpath query except the /*/ part.  With this syntax my identical situation query would not return any nodes, but if I changed the first characters to simple be two slashes // the query would return as expected.  Any explanation on that part?

Comment: Four years later I'm running into the same issue and your solution fits perfectly - cheers Wayne!

Answer (score 4):

You can try this way :

```
//a[
    @class='B' 
        and 
    preceding-sibling::a[@class='A'] 
        and 
    following-sibling::a[@class='A']
   ]
```

Above XPath will select all `<a class='B'>` element(s) between the two `<a class='A'>` elements.

Answer (score -1):

try it this way:

```
//a[@class='B'][preceding-sibling::*[1][name()='a'][@class='A']]
```