# Scraping based on date

Tags: xpath, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape data from a website, which does not seem to have to many clases in the tags. However i'm still wondering whether it is possible to scrape the titles from today using xpath.

So that it only retrieve the titles which is from 09/4 - 2015?

url: http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=96

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since date is unique `10/4 - 2015`, you might locate a `b` tag node using xpath's `contents()`, see html [here](http://joxi.ru/LmG7ogEidyoJml):

```
//b[contains(., '10/4 - 2015')]
```

then based on this node you go to its parent and siblings, smth. like this (not tested):

```
//b[contains(., '10/4 - 25')]/parent::div/siblings::div
```

### Update

Since the current date items go at the bottom, here accorting to the html all the following-sibling nodes pertain to this data (google [`xpath sibling after`](https://www.google.lv/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=xpath%20siblings%20after&oq=xpath%20siblings&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.8911j0j7))

```
//b[contains(., '10/4 - 25')]/parent::div/following-sibling::div[@class='newsItem']
```

See test [here](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/50e58fa17575ea5f76c6a452e2bdbf5a). If you want to fetch divs inbetween, then explore [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161766/xpath-select-all-following-siblings-until-another-sibling)

Comment: It return the date div however i cant seem to make it work getting the article titles which is under that date