# How to get all elements between two nodes with XPATH?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I have HTML code like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3><a href="#" name='title1'>Title</a></h3>
        <div>para1</div>
        <div>para2</div>
        <div>para3</div>
        <h3><a href="#" name='title2'>Title</a></h3>
        <div>para4</div>
        <div>para5</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What I want is:

```
<div>para1</div>
<div>para2</div>
<div>para3</div>
```

So I want to get the first part in this html. I need to ignore the second part.

for now I just work out this way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8

import unittest

from lxml import etree

class SearchPara(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        with open('test.html') as f:
            self.html = f.read()

    def test_parse_html(self):
        paras = ''
        page = etree.HTML(self.html)
        a_ele = page.xpath("//h3/a[@name='title1']/..")

        if a_ele is None or len(a_ele) < 1:
            return paras

        para = a_ele[0].xpath('following-sibling::*[1][name(.) != "h3"]')
        while para is not None and len(para) > 0:
            print para
            paras += etree.tostring(para[0])
            para = para[0].xpath('following-sibling::*[1][name(.) != "h3"]')

        print paras


    def tearDown(self):
      pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

As you can see, this is a little bit complicated, what I want to know if I have beeter way to do this?

Comment: @mins you puzzled me, `p[a]` means `All P with an A child`, but the `<div>` are not children of `<a>`

Comment: @mins I want to get the first`<div>para1</div><div>para2</div><div>para3</div>` and the second `<div>para4</div><div>para5</div>` as my result

Comment: Like you edited it, now it seems you want to select all <div> regardless of other criteria. Maybe you should clarify what you want with a better example.

Comment: @mins yes, exactly. In fact, I am doing this because I want to get all paragraphs associate with a title. Can I do this?

Comment: You want to get all siblings from a starting point, until some sibling is found: See [XPath : select all following siblings until another sibling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161766/xpath-select-all-following-siblings-until-another-sibling)

Comment: roger, your question is not clear. It is unclear what the rules are for selecting nodes in your example. Please edit your question and show _another_ sample. A [**good sample**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) contains all the complexity present in your actual data. Show us a sample where some of the `div` elements should _not_ be selected. Also, samples must be **complete** documents.

Comment: Please show us what you tried so far. Furthermore, your assertion does not apply. The `<div>`with para1 is **not** followed by an `<a>` until the one preceding the `<h3>`. And since there is no further `<a>`, nothing matches.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg as you insists, I have give you all codes, you can test in your machine.

Comment: @MathiasMüller I have change my question completely, maybe this is clearly for now.

Comment: @roger: I do not insist on my purpose. You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no general way to select elements between 2 elements using XPath 1.0.

The same output still can be achieved if we can define the assertion differently. For example, by selecting `<div>`s having nearest preceding sibling `<a>` value equals `"Title: Part I"` :

```
//div[preceding-sibling::a[1][. = 'Title: Part I']]
```

and selecting the next `<div>`s group only require changing the `<a>` criteria :

```
//div[preceding-sibling::a[1][. = 'Title: Part II']]
```

The test method to see above xpath in action :

```
def test_parse_html(self):
    page = etree.HTML(self.html)
    paras = ''
    para = page.xpath("//div[preceding-sibling::a[1][. = 'Title: Part I']]")
    for p in para:
        paras += etree.tostring(p)

    print paras
```

Side note. xpath for populating `a_ele` in your code can be simplified this way :

```
a_ele = page.xpath("//a[h3 = 'Title: Part I']")
```

or even further, since the only text element within the `<a>` is "Title: Part I" :

```
a_ele = page.xpath("//a[. = 'Title: Part I']")
```

Comment: I am so so so so sorry, I need to bother you again, my situation is  a little bit different now, I tried to use your tips to simplify my program, can you give me a tip again?

Comment: Same approach with slight change to the xpath expression : `//div[preceding-sibling::h3[1][a/@name = 'title1']]` ?