# group siblings by identifying the first node of a certain type in sequence

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Not sure if that description is the best...but given this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <type1 num="1" first="1"/>
    <type1 num="2" />
    <type2 num="3" />
    <type2 num="4" />
    <type1 num="5" first="2"/>
    <type1 num="6" />
    <type2 num="7" />
    <type2 num="8" />
    <type1 num="9" first="3"/>
    <type1 num="10" />
    <type2 num="11" />
    <type2 num="12" />

</root>
```

I want to deepen the hierarchy and add a new 'group' node every time I hit the first in a sequence of type1 nodes. (note: the @first is there just so I could see what exact node the template was picking up...I don't want to use it to start the group)

Here is my stylesheet.

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:key name="kFirstText" match="*" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::type1[not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::type1])][1])"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <newroot>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </newroot>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="type1[not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::type1])]">
    <group>
        <type1>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="first-in-group">true</xsl:attribute>
        </type1>
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('kFirstText', generate-id())"/>
    </group>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And the result I am getting is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<newroot>
    <group><type1 num="1" first="1" first-in-group="true"/><type1 num="2"/><type2 num="3"/><type2 num="4"/><type1 num="5" first="2"/></group>
    <group><type1 num="5" first="2" first-in-group="true"/><type1 num="6"/><type2 num="7"/><type2 num="8"/><type1 num="9" first="3"/></group>
    <group><type1 num="9" first="3" first-in-group="true"/><type1 num="10"/><type2 num="11"/><type2 num="12"/></group>
</newroot>
```

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161766/xpath-select-all-following-siblings-until-another-sibling) which got me pretty close, but as you can see in the output, the first instance of the type1 node is being duplicated in the first two groups.

I also realized I'm a little fuzzy on exactly what the key is picking up. My read is it's picking up any node that follows the immediate preceding instance of a type1 that does not have a type1 right behind it...is that right?

I also tried to exclude that node(@num="5") in the @match using the same xpath in the template, but that was just ignored. Any idea how to accomplish what I described above?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
<xsl:key name="kFirstText" match="*[not(self::type1[not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::type1])])]" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::type1[not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::type1])][1])"/>
```

This excludes the "leader" nodes from the group retrieved by the key.

Comment: thanks, I had tried using match="type2|type1[not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::type1])]" but that was ignored...yours worked perfectly